# Preload spritsheet asynchronously in cocos2d-x 3 and use it

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Is this the correct what to pre-load the spritsheet asynchronously and use it appropriately in other scene after removing loading screen?

```
   // load the texture into the cache 
   Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImageAsync("ingame.png", 
    [](cocos2d::Texture2D *texture) {

        SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("ingame.plist", texture);

        // here remove loading screen and go to ingame scene to use the loaded spritesheet
    }
);


    // use the loaded spritesheet in ingame scene
    auto bg = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("ingame_bg.png");
    bg->setPosition(origin + visibleSize / 2);
    addChild(bg, 0);
```

As I understand, after calling `addImageAsync` the `.png` file is loaded into the memory of GPU but there is no info yet about the image positions in the spritesheet. Hence we call also `SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("ingame.plist", texture);` to ask cocos2d-x to parse the `.plist` file and understand where are the images in the spritesheet. Does it make sense?

Comment: I just do this: `SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("sprites.plist");`

Comment: But is does not pre-load, right? And please tell me if my conclusion about what do these function are right or wrong?

Comment: If you look at the source for `addSpriteFramesWithFile()` it surely does pre-load.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, `addSpriteFramesWithFile()` does preloading for you.

Check the source:

```
Texture2D *texture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage(texturePath.c_str());

if (texture)
{
    addSpriteFramesWithDictionary(dict, texture);
    _loadedFileNames->insert(pszPlist);
}
else
{
    CCLOG("cocos2d: SpriteFrameCache: Couldn't load texture");
}
```

Comment: Look the source deeper: in this `TextureCache::addImage(` function it obtains texture from map if it is already loaded, instead of loading again.

Comment: To be sure, are you saying look at this function: `Texture2D * TextureCache::addImage(const std::string &path)`

Comment: Yes, exactly! It is the one which is used in `addSpriteFramesWithFile`.

Comment: ok let me look at it some more, to me it looks like it is creating a new Texture2D.

Comment: according to the Cocos2d-x team this does preload the SpriteFrames if they don't already exist.